# Conda rst2pdf not found although on anaconda.org

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, python-sphinx, rst2pdf

I am using anaconda as package manager and tried to install rst2pdf to be able to output a PDF using sphinx for a python program.

However I get the following readback when I try to run the [published command](https://anaconda.org/dfroger/rst2pdf):

```
conda install -c dfroger rst2pdf
```

```
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - rst2pdf
```

I don't know a work around for this issue. Is it maybe a problem, that rst2pdf on conda seems to be for linux only? I'm confused on this.

Maybe there is another way to be able to output a pdf file using sphinx and python through conda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `dfroger` is just some random user's channel, which hasn't been updated in two years, and unless you know/trust that person you should not be attempting to install from there. Otherwise, there aren't any Conda channels to source that package from, so instead follow [the recommended installation](https://github.com/rst2pdf/rst2pdf#install-from-pypi) and install through PyPI - just make sure to activate the Conda environment first.

```
conda activate your_env
pip install rst2pdf
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't know that it works like this as well. Wonderful!